# Best data structure to store temperature readings over time

Tags: redis

I used to work with SQL like MySQL, Postgres or MSSQL.

Now I want to play with Redis. I'm working on a little home project, that I think is the best choice for starting using Redis.

I have a machine that reads temperature (indoor and outdoor) and humidity. I need to store the readings into Redis. Can you help me to understand the best data structure to do so?

Other than this data I need to store the time (ex. unix timestamp) of the temperature reading for use plotting a graphic.

I installed Redis read the documentation, so I understand the commands and data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is your first Redis project and it's a home project, I'd be careful about being to careful.  Here's a couple ways to consider designing it (NOTE: I only dug deep into REDIS this past weekend so hopefully others will weigh in).

IDEA 1:

- Four ordered sets
- KEY for sets are "indoor_temps", "outdoor_temps", "indoor_humidity", "outdoor_humidity"
- VALUES are the temperatures / humidities
- SCORE is the date stored as EPOCH

IDEA 2:

- Four types of keys (best shown by example)
- datetime_key = /year:2014/month:07/day:12/hour:07/minute:32/second:54
- type_keys = [indoor_temps, outdoor_temps, indoor_humidity, outdoor_humidity]
- keys are of form type + "/" + datetime_key
- values are the temp and humidity itself

You probably want to implement some initial design and then work with the data immediately - graph it, do stats, etc. Whatever you plan to do with it.  That will expose flaws and if they are major, flush the database and try again.  These designs should really only take ~1 hour to implement since the only thing you're really changing is a few Redis commands and some string manipulation to convert the data to keys.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your help. Fot first try i followed first idea.
So i can use "ZADD indoor_temps 1403189362 32.3", "ZADD indoor_temps 1403189382 30.3" and so on.

At this point i can use ZRANGEBYSCORE for extract the element of last X hours for graph them. In this way if my machine goes down i can't control if the sampling time is correct (for plot data).

So i can use "ZRANGE indoor_temps -60 -1" for extract last 60 sample (one sample for minutes).

What do you think?

Comment: @user3756354 Sounds like you're asking more of a UX question for yourself ;)  I'm not sure I have an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

I like Tony's suggestions, but I'll also throw out another possibility.

- 4 lists
- keys are "indoor_temps", "outdoor_temps", "indoor_humidity", "outdoor_humidity"
- values are of the form < timestamp >_< reading > ie.( "1403197981_27.2" )

Push items onto the front of the list using LPUSH.  Get a set of readings using LRANGE.  The list will always be ordered by the time of the reading.  Obviously split the value on "_" to get your time and reading...

In all honesty, this will give the same properties as Tony's first example, with slightly worse lookup performance, but [better memory usage](http://support.redistogo.com/kb/info/memory-costs-of-redis-data-structures).  I'm guessing for this project you'll be neither memory, nor CPU constrained, so the choice is probably not an issue.  That said, if you expect to be saving 100's of thousands or more readings, I would suggest the list unless you want to consume a large portion of your system's memory.

Also, it's a good idea to call EXPIRE on your entries with some reasonable TTL that encompasses the length of time you want to save the readings for.  If your plan is to have them live in perpetuity then you may want to look at backing them up to a disk DB over time, and just use Redis as a quick lookup cache for recent readings.

Comment: In my case all data (temperature and humidity) is  readed in the same time so have the same timestamp. 

 - five list
 - keys are "indoor_temp", "outdoor_temp", "indoor_humidity", "outdoor_humidity" and "timestamp"
 - values are a float data for temperature and humidity and a int for timestamp

At this point i will use LPUSH for all them.

What do you thank about?

Comment: Sure, that would also work.  It would make me nervous though.  If one of your pushes ever failed then your 5 lists would be out of sync from that point on...  If you use pipelining, you mitigate the potential issue since network issues shouldn't cause one to fail but the rest to succeed.  But I am still not a fan of situations where your data can get out of sync with a single failed write.  Mine and Tony's solutions don't suffer from that issue.  Worst case would be that you'd be missing a reading at one timestamp if a write fails.  Subsequent readings would continue to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all answer, I choose this strucure:

- 4 lists: tempIN, tempOut, humidIN and humidOUT
- values are: [value]:[timestamp]. For example: "25.4:1403615247"

As suggested from wallacer i want to backup old entries out from Redis.
For main frontend i need only last two days of sample.

For example i can create Redis RDB file snapshot and "trim" the live lists. This solution is not convenient in the event that, in the future you want to recover old values​​.

Do you have any tips on what kind of procedure to adopt to store the data? Maybe use of SQLIte DB?